# Where can I find documentation for possible raised Exceptions for existing Python3 API's?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

If I have a small piece of code such as,

```
try:
    file = open(file_name):
except IOError as e:
    ...
else:
    f.read()
finally:
    f.close()
```

I understand that I need to use the Python's `with` but this is purely for educational code.

In this example, if the file has not yet been opened is it possible to get an error from the call `f.read()`? I mean I could add a breakpoint and then delete the file after it has been opened.

However, without thinking of all the scenarios where can I find all the possible Exceptions being raised from `f.read()` I cannot seem to find them by looking at the Python3 Documentation.

Comment: To clarify, is your question _specifically_ about the `.read` method? I hope that's the case, because your title seems to be asking for _all_ existing python APIs, which is a bit too broad.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy

Comment: @GinoMempin In this case it will be specifically for `.read`, I was hoping to learn it for one method and then apply it to others.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Where can I read which possible exceptions can be raised from specific methods being called? In particular, `.read()`

Comment: The [open() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) specifically say it returns `OSError` on failure, and further reading for `errors='strict'` the default) says `ValueError` can be raised when reading/writing the file.  `open` can return different types of IO objects.  For example [TextIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#id1).  So depending on the mode you open, more documentation can be read.  I only noticed `OSError`, `ValueError` and `RuntimeError` in certain reentrancy conditionds.  Bascially, read the docs...it's there.

Comment: Note that any of the more specific `OSError` and `ValueError` exceptions can be caught as well, such as `FileNotFoundError` or `UnicodeDecodeError`.  You can also catch generic `Exception` or `BaseException` if needed to handle unexpected conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, all exception are instances of a base exception (BaseException) class, from the documentation you can see all the base exceptions that libraries can implement, and a more detailed explanation.
Here the link: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Doc/library/exceptions.rst

Comment: Where would it be found for specifically `.read()`?

Comment: Here you can find some examples from the documentation on how to handle file.read() exceptions. [HERE](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Doc/tutorial/errors.rst#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Your first stop should indeed be the official Python documentation.

Here's the one for [`.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) which mentions some Exceptions it could raise, such as:

> `'strict'` to raise a ValueError exception if there is an encoding error

Now for `.read()`, it depends on what `.open()` returns, which the docs says returns a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), which in turn has different types:

> The type of file object returned by the open() function depends on the
> mode. When open() is used to open a file in a text mode (`'w'`, `'r'`,
> `'wt'`, `'rt'`, etc.), it returns a subclass of [io.TextIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase)
> (specifically [io.TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)). When used to open a file in a binary
> mode with buffering, the returned class is a subclass of
> [io.BufferedIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase). The exact class varies: in read binary mode, it
> returns an [io.BufferedReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader); in write binary and append binary modes,
> it returns an [io.BufferedWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedWriter), and in read/write mode, it returns an
> [io.BufferedRandom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedRandom). When buffering is disabled, the raw stream, a
> subclass of [io.RawIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase), [io.FileIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.FileIO), is returned.

Let's say it returned a text file object, so then you *again* go through the documentation for [io.TextIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) and [io.TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper). There are some hints there as well as to what kind of Exceptions are raised by that class and its methods. Under `io.TextIOBase`, you'll find the method description for [.read()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read), which indeed does not explicitly say the types of Exceptions raised.

If you can't find it from the docs, it can be a bit daunting but you can always check the source at https://github.com/python/cpython. Here's the one for the `io` module (as of Python 3.9.6): https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.6/Lib/_pyio.py.

Specifically for [.open()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.6/Lib/_pyio.py#L43), you'll see all the different `raise ...` codes that you can catch. For `.read`, again you'll have to find the correct class. Here's a snippet from `io.TextIOWrapper`'s [.read()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.6/Lib/_pyio.py#L1638):

```
    def read(self, size=None):
        self._checkReadable()
        if size is None:
            size = -1
        else:
            try:
                size_index = size.__index__
            except AttributeError:
                raise TypeError(f"{size!r} is not an integer")
```

which shows it can raise a `TypeError` if you passed a non-integer size.

Also, as with all Exceptions, sometimes you don't need to specifically catch each and every one of them. Sometimes you just need to catch the parent Exception class. For that, as [mentioned in Mark Tolonen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855134/where-can-i-find-documentation-for-possible-raised-exceptions-for-existing-pytho?noredirect=1#comment121687534_68855134), you can check the [Exception Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) to see which ones you only need to handle.

Finally, there is nothing wrong though with doing trial-and-error to see what happens, like what you said:

> I mean I could add a breakpoint and then delete the file after it has been opened.

This is where tests come in handy. You write a test for some behavior and error case, your code will fail with an unhandled Exception, so then you update your code to properly handle that exception.